# Problem with tables rate - he does not show in frontend

Tags: table-rates

I have today written and uploaded a tables rate guess. 
Unfortunately, everything works but i cannot choose Austria?
Maybe something must be separately enabled?

I want to do is:
Shipping Germany - 0- 49.99€ - 4,90€ shipping cost 
Shipping Germany - From 50€ - Free shpping
Austria - at the beginning 16€ shpping costs

The code is:

Land,Region/Bundesland,PLZ,"Zwischensumme (und mehr)",Versandpreis
DEU,*,*,0.0000,4.9000
DEU,*,*,49.9900,0.0000
AT,*,*,0.0000,16.0000

( there is a star between the commas but it will not Show here in the Forum)

I have item with 7% and 19% tax - maybe is this a Problem?
I have uploaded the csv. file - after the upload i tried to buy something but they don´t Show me other Shipping costs and i cannot choose Austria.

Thanks for help.

Daniel

[image]
[image]
[image]